# Set MIN value in a column in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to set the minium value in all the column by the elements in the group by. The problem for the table is the column `lastupdate`,some values have `'0001-01-01'`, so when I apply `MIN()` it doesn't give me a correct value.

I trying with this code, but doesn't work. I want to have the `MIN` value by `period` and `coddoc` in all the column.

```
SELECT  
    period, 
    coddoc, 
    (
        CASE WHEN MIN(lastupdate)='0001-01-01' 
            THEN MIN(lastupdate) 
            ELSE MIN(lastupdate) 
        END 
    ) as lastupdate 
FROM table 
GROUP BY period, coddoc;
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If `lastupdate` is a `date` column you should use a *date literal*, i.e. `DATE '0001-01-01'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take advantage of the fact that `MIN()` ignores `NULL` values:

```
SELECT 
    period, 
    coddoc, 
    MIN(CASE WHEN lastupdate = '0001-01-01' THEN NULL ELSE lastupdate END) as lastupdate 
FROM table 
GROUP BY period, coddoc;
```

---

NB : as commented by [@dnoeth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2527905/dnoeth), the CASE expression can be shortened as :

```
NULLIF(lastupdate, '0001-01-01')
```

Comment: Or shorter: `MIN(NULLIF(lastupdate, '0001-01-01'))`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just filter in the `where` clause?

```
SELECT period, coddoc, MIN(lastupdate) as lastupdate 
FROM table 
WHERE lastupdate > '0001-01-01'
GROUP BY period, coddoc;
```

Comment: @VictoriaUbaldo . . . This is simpler and should have better performance.